# Why can't I add my home folder to the Mac OS X Lion Finder Sidebar?

Tags: mac, finder, sidebar, osx-lion

After upgrading to Lion, I'm unable to add my home folder to the favorites section of my Finder's sidebar. I tried it through `Finder Preferences` by ticking the checkbox, but it deactivates itself after I click it. I've also tried dragging the home folder into the sidebar, but that doesn't do anything either (no error message) :(

Comment: Can you add any other folders into the sidebar?

Comment: Yep, everything else works fine

Comment: Does deleting ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist and com.apple.sidebarlists.plist.lockfile and restarting Finder do anything?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Apparently Apple has fixed the problem mentioned in the question. In Lion OS X version 10.7.3, I find that you can click the checkbox for your home folder in Finder Preferences -> Sidebar (which is unchecked by default), and it will stay checked, after which it shows your home folder in the sidebar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem, turning off legacy FileVault, as Andrey suggested, solved the problem for me.

Legacy FileVault encrypts the user's home directory only, whereas FileVault in Lion encrypts the entire disk. I'm almost sure, adding the home folder to the sidebar will work with Lion's standard FileVault activated.

Comment: Just wanted to chime in that this matches my experience as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue until I turned off FileVault on my home folder. And now I can add my home folder to the sidebar in Finder.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble finding my home folder in Finder. An easy way to find it if you have the same problem is to open up Termainal and type "open ~" (the ~ means your home directory).